# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Pro Webmaster's [third moderator election](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Stephen Ostermiller] [image: bybe]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/1456016/0).

Comment: Well done guys! :)

Comment: *1,337 voters were eligible* haha :) Congrats to both of you!

Comment: congratulations you both! you deserved it ;)

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations to you both! Welcome aboard. We had a lot of excellent candidates and hopefully they'll get another shot before too long.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations guys!

Good luck for all work you will perform for the community and even if I lost this election, I will continue to help you to keep this website cleaner.